Live Person SDK
I am using:
await conversation.sendRichText(content);
by 'lp-messaging-sdk';
but when I send an image with text without buttons I get 201 response but the message does not appear in the conversation on WhatsApp
Can anyone tell me what is the reason here?
I am trying to send an image template with text to a WhatsApp conversation
I get a response without problems in Postman but the message does not appear in WhatsApp
